# Backup script not generating file

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following script to perform an sql dump and export it to a .sql (I've omitted my mysql details but they are all correct.)

**Code:**

```
<?php
    $mysqlDatabaseName ='x';
    $mysqlUserName ='';
    $mysqlPassword ='';
    $mysqlHostName ='';
    $mysqlExportPath ='backup.sql';
    
    
    $command='mysqldump --opt -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' > ' .$mysqlExportPath;
    exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
    switch($worked){
    case 0:
    echo 'The database <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b> was successfully stored in the following path '.getcwd().'/' .$mysqlExportPath .'</b>';
    break;
    case 1:
    echo 'An error occurred when exporting <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b> zu '.getcwd().'/' .$mysqlExportPath .'</b>';
    break;
    case 2:
    echo 'An export error has occurred, please check the following information: <br/><br/><table><tr><td>MySQL Database Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL User Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlUserName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Password:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Host Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlHostName .'</b></td></tr></table>';
    break;
    }
    ?>
```

**Output:** The database x was successfully stored in the following path /dev/backups/backup.sql

The code functions as if the backup performed successfully, however there is no .sql file generated.

I've got debugging enabled, but no mysql errors are being generated - any suggestions perhaps on why it's not being generated or how to troubleshoot?

**Update 1:** After some further troubleshooting $worked and $output are empty variables after the exec() function is run.

Comment: Did you check that command directly in your shell? does it work? also did you debug `$output` and `$worked` vars without any conditions?

Comment: Also remember if you are running this from the web server it is running as (well not you) so maybe you need to fully path the `mysqldump` executable

Comment: @biesior - Thanks for the advice. $worked and $output seems to have a value of nothing after the exec command is run.